# Conjugates of $12^{1/5}+54^{1/5}-144^{1/5}+648^{1/5}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

After much manual computation I found the minimal polynomial to be $x^5+330x-4170$, although I would very much like to know if there's a clever way to see this. I suspect there is from seeing that the prime factorisations of the four integers are as various powers of $2$ and $3$ and because the number can be written as: $$12^{1/5}+54^{1/5}-(12^{1/5})^2+(12^{1/5}\cdot 54^{1/5})$$
But I haven't yet been able to find anything better than manual computation of the fifth power.

However, from here I am lost, I'm not sure how to solve this equation. A quick internet search returns much information on the general case in terms of the "Bring-Gerrard normal form" but the book from which this problem was taken hasn't gone into any detail on general methods for solving polynomials, so I am trying to find a solution that doesn't require any heavy machinery.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: Note that $12 = \dfrac{18^5}{54^3}$, maybe?

Comment: If you already know one root $r$, divide the polynomial by $x-r$. Then you get a polynomial of degree $4$ for which you have formulas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: Letting $\alpha = 54^{1/5}$ the above ends up $18\alpha^{-3} + \alpha - 6\alpha^{-1} + 18\alpha^{-2}$, I think.

Comment: @Clayton "Introductory Algebraic Number Theory" by Alaca and Williams

Comment: Use a computer to help you make the computations. $(x^5+330x-4170)/(x-r)=x^4-6^{1/5} (-2^{1/5}+2^{3/5} 3^{1/5}-3^{2/5}-2^{2/5} 3^{3/5}) x^3+6^{1/5} (-9 2^{1/5}+7 2^{3/5} 3^{1/5}+2 3^{2/5}+4 2^{2/5} 3^{3/5}) x^2+6^{1/5} (24 2^{1/5}+9 2^{3/5} 3^{1/5}+56 3^{2/5}-21 2^{2/5} 3^{3/5}) x+62 2^{3/5} 3^{4/5}-156 2^{1/5} 3^{3/5}+129 2^{4/5} 3^{2/5}+348 2^{2/5} 3^{1/5}+66$

Comment: @RGB Thank you, but I was trying to find a solution that minimised the amount of computation, in particular one that could be done without the aid of a computer or general formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x$ be your number.
You can immediately see that $x \in \Bbb Q(12^{1/5}, 54^{1/5})$ (or even $x \in \Bbb Q(2^{1/5},3^{1/5})$, from your remark about the prime factors).

It is not too hard to show that its normal closure is $\Bbb Q(\zeta_5,12^{1/5},54^{1/5}) ( = \Bbb Q(\zeta_5,2^{1/5},3^{1/5}))$, and from there you can investigate the relevant Galois group and find the conjugates.

However, you have found that the number is actually of degree $5$, which should be a surprise at first : the situation is simpler than that.
After investigating a bit, we see that $54 = 12^3 / 2^5$, and so $54^{1/5}$ is already in $\Bbb Q(12^{1/5})$, and letting $y = 12^{1/5}$, we have $x = y + y^3/2 - y^2 + y^4/2$.

So now the problem reduces to finding the conjugates of $y = 12^{1/5}$. Its minimal polynomial is clearly $y^5-12=0$, and its $5$ roots are the the $\zeta_5^k 12^{1/5}$ where $\zeta_5$ is a primitive $5$th root of $1$. To get the conjugates of $x$ you simply replace $y$ with any of its conjugate in the above formula for $x$

---

In simpler terms : your calculations should actually show that "if $y^5 = 12$, then $(y+y^3/2-y^2+y^4/2)$ is a root of $x^5+330x-4170 = 0$". By using $5$ different $y$ such that $y^5 = 12$, you obtain $5$ roots of $x^5+330x-4170 = 0$. However, proving that they are distinct, and that the polynomial is irreducible, doesn't seem easy to do.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know anything about normal closures or Galois groups and I don't know why replacing the $y$ with it's conjugates in the expression for $x$ gives the conjugates of $x$, could you please clarify?

Comment: $5$ divides $330$ and $4170$ and $5^2$ doesn't divide $4170$.

Comment: To show they are different: one is real, the other four are two pairs of conjugates to each other. So, it is enough to prove that theone with $\zeta_5$ is non-zero and different from the one with $\zeta_5^2$. The one with $\zeta_5$ is non zero because the polynomial doesn't have zero as a root. To check the one with $\zeta_5$ and $\zeta_5^2$ are different subtract and check the real part is non zero.

Comment: As RGB points out, the polynomial is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion. If we write the solutions to $y^5=54$ as $r\omega,r\omega^2,\dots,r\omega^5$ where $r=|54^{1/5}|$ and $\omega=e^{2\pi i/5}$ then it is easily checked that substituting these values of $y$ into the expression $y+y^3/2-y^2+y^4/2$ are distinct since $\omega$ is degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the expressions are all different linear combinations of four distinct powers of $\omega$.

Comment: As to showing that $y^{12}=5$ means that $y+y^3/2-y^2+y^4/2$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial, I am happy to assume that taking the fifth power of $x=y+y^3/2-y^2+y^4/2$ gives $4170-330x$, although again, I'm not sure how to actually show this without much computation...

(And thanks very much for updating your answer, I understand the argument much better now!)

Comment: @TomOldfield : actually, you don't need to compute the polynomial, but only that it exists and has degree $5$. This tells you that $x$ has at most $4$ other conjugates. (however it comes with the cost that you don't know if the polynomial is irreducible). To show they are distinct, you need to know that $\omega$ is of degree $4$ over $\Bbb Q(12^{1/5})$ and not just over $\Bbb Q$. Without some Galois theory to give a nice picture of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_5, 12^{1/5})$ and its automorphisms and subfields, it is hard to do all that without computation.

Comment: @mercio That's a very good point about showing where $\omega$ is degree $4$ over, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Noting that $12=\dfrac{18^5}{54^3}$ and $144 = \dfrac{6^5}{54}$, letting $\alpha = 54^{1/5}$, we see that the above is:

$$18\alpha^{-3} + \alpha - 6\alpha^{-1} + 18\alpha^{-2} = \frac{18\alpha^2 + 54\alpha - 6\alpha^4 + 18\alpha^3}{54}$$

Now replace $\alpha$ by conjugates of $\alpha$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why replacing $\alpha$ with it's conjugates would give the conjugates we're looking for, could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misremembering, but I thought if $f\in\mathbb Q[x]$ and $\alpha$ is any algebraic number, and $\alpha_1$ is a conjugate of $\alpha$, then $f(\alpha_1)$ is a conjugate of $f(\alpha)$. This doesn't prove it gives *all* the conjugates, of course - then you have to prove that you get five distinct conjugates. @TomOldfield

Comment: No, I'm definitely remembering correctly. In the splitting field for $z^{5}-54$, there is an automorphism defined by$\alpha\to\alpha_1$. The automorphism must send $f(\alpha)$ to $f(\alpha_1)$, and, since it is an automorphism, if $p(f(\alpha))=0$ then $p(f(\alpha_1))=0$. So $f(\alpha_1)$ is a root of the minimal polynomial of $f(\alpha)$. @TomOldfield

Comment: The only unclear part is whether $f(\alpha_1)=f(\alpha)$. I haven't tried to prove it here, but I'm pretty sure this doesn't happen in this case. Essentially, you only need to choose one conjugate $\alpha_1$.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much, I think I understand now! (Field automorphisms haven't been covered in the book so far.)

Comment: Ah, okay. That would make it less clear :) @TomOldfield